# How to get data when combo box is selected windows Form c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
private void namecombo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-IIBSL6N;Initial Catalog=sales_management;Integrated Security=True"))
            {
                sqlconn.Open();
                SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Name = '" + this.namecombo.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' ", sqlconn);
                sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
                adapter.Fill(dtbl);
                foreach(DataRow dr in dtbl.Rows)
                {
                    accountnumtxtbox.Text = dr["acount_name"].ToString();
                    phonetxtbox.Text = dr["phone_number"].ToString();
                    officenumtxtbox.Text = dr["office_number"].ToString();
                    addresstxtbox.Text = dr["Address"].ToString();
                }
                sqlconn.Close();
            }
        }
```

this doesn't work at all whats the problem?

Comment: _"doesn't work at all"_ is not a question. How should it work? How it actualy work? What things happens when you run this code?

Comment: Have you heard about Sql Injection? Don't concatenate values from user fields with your query. Use parameters (SqlParameter). Also, don't SELECT *. Instead, include columns you actually need in your application.

Comment: @vasily.sib when i run it the text in textbox doesnt change and i cant figure out the problem

Comment: have you try to debug it?

Comment: You don't have to ExecuteNonQuery on your command. Just use the SqlDataAdapter. Also, include the SqlDataAdapter in an using.

Comment: @NițuAlexandru i am using the data table to do the same thing as select specific column and yes i usually use stored procedures but its hard and time taking for this part of my coding..

Comment: @vasily.sib yes i have there isnt any error only doesnt work

Comment: @NițuAlexandru nothing changed

Comment: Do you get any rows? Are you aware that ,if it were working, your text boxes would show data from only the last row because you overwrite them in each loop iteration?

Comment: @Crowcoder how come i thought when i put WHERE in the sql command it selects the specific row where the name is selected in the combo box

Comment: If there is only one row then you won't have a problem but then you don't need a loop. A WHERE clause doesn't mean it will return one row, it depends on what your filter criteria is. If `Name` is a unique field then you will get one row, or zero rows if there is no match.

Comment: Have you looked at what Command that code is generating from the debugger? If the combobox is not just a list of strings then I don't think the `SelectedItem.ToString()` is what you expect it to be. Getting familiar with the debugger is *critical* to programming.

Comment: @Crowcoder yeah im planing to make the name column to be unique...but i cant seem to underestand the reason nothing is written in the textboxes when the name is selected from the combo box

Comment: @Crowcoder actually it is only a list of strings

Comment: Debug it and look at the sql string you generate. Put your cursor on the line with `sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` and press F9. Then press F5. When you break in the debugger hover over `sqlcmd` and look at the `CommandText` property.

Comment: @Crowcoder i tried it there isnt any errors

Comment: Nobody can help if you can even tell us what the code is doing, what results you get, what the inputs are, etc. We don't have your database, we can't run your program, we don't know what is in the combobox.

Comment: @Crowcoder in the combo box are names in both english and persian and what im telling you is that i cant get any result from this code... i know its not normal but it neither has any result nor any error to debug

Comment: What the combobox shows you can be different than *the objects bound to it*. Comboboxes have a display member property and a value member property so it still not clear to me if the selected item is actually just a string. You should be able to debug your code, get the SQL string that is generated, look at it and see if it is correct, and run it in a tool like SQL Server Management Studio to see if it gets results. This may tell you exactly what your problem is or at least give you an idea what to look at next.

Comment: @Crowcoder the combo box is bounded to the database i created in sql server and iv already used the stored procedure in another set of codes and it worked...but thanks for your answeres

Comment: @Crowcoder i fixed it you must use combox.text instead of combobox.selecteditem

Comment: It works in your case but often the displayed text is not the value represented in the database so you can't say you have to always use the `Text` property. I urge you to practice some debugging skills - you would have been able to see the problem in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-IIBSL6N;Initial Catalog=sales_management;Integrated Security=True"))   
{  
    sqlconn.Open();  
    SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Name = N'" + this.customergrid.SelectedRows + "' ", sqlconn);  
    sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
    DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();  
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);  
    adapter.Fill(dtbl);  
    foreach (DataRow dr in dtbl.Rows)  
    {  
        accountnumtxtbox.Text = dr["acount_name"].ToString();  
        phonetxtbox.Text = dr["phone_number"].ToString();  
        officenumtxtbox.Text = dr["office_number"].ToString();  
        addresstxtbox.Text = dr["Address"].ToString();  
    }  
    sqlconn.Close();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to do it this way, just adapt it to your needs.

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE LastName = @lastName AND FirstName = @firstName";
        UserAccount account = UserAccount.Empty;

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlConnection))
        {
            SqlParameter _firstName = new SqlParameter("@firstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            SqlParameter _lastName = new SqlParameter("@lastName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);

            _firstName.Value = account.FirstName;
            _lastName.Value = account.LastName;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(_firstName);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(_lastName);

            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            adapter.Fill(dataSet);

            if (dataSet.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                if (dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    DataRow row = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0];

                    //fill your properties with the results
                }
            }

            adapter.Dispose();
            dataSet.Dispose();
        }
```